# Bootstrap How to get element clicked to collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a panel with two links, linkEdit and linkShow, we use to collapse/expand it the panel. I need to know which link was clicked. I tried $triggers but that returns both trigger elements.

The reason for doing this is I only want linkEdit to expand only and the linkShow can expand and collapse. The idea was to return false if the linkEdit is clicked and true if linkShow is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#collapsePanel').on('hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        console.info($(e.target).data('bs.collapse'));
        var triggers = $(e.target).data('bs.collapse').$trigger;
        console.info($(this));            
    })
});
```

Comment: Checking this https://www.quackit.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_3/tutorial/bootstrap_collapse.cfm might help you

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't show how to get the element that triggered the hide.

Answer (score 0):

Just use JQuery to check if any of it's children were clicked, attaching an onClick listener to every link inside the collapsePanel or outside (I'm not sure I understood you very well):

```
$("#collapsePanel .link_class").click(function() {
    if ( $(this).attr('class') === "linkEdit" ) {
        // Collapse your #collapsePanel
    } else {
        // Don't collapse your panel
    }
}
```

If you want to only display a few elements inside the collapsePanel, use the `$(".your_hidden_elements").hide()` to hide them.