# Get clicked element on show.bs.collapse with bootstrap 4 Collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bootstrap-4

I have a serie of buttons, all callapsing the same panel.
I'm trying to get the clicked element that opened the panel so I can dynamically inject some data in the panel.

I need, if possible, to get the element on the `show.bs.collapse` event so I can inject the data before the panel is displayed

here is my html :

```
<div class='container'>
     <div class='buttons'>
          <a id='link-one' data-toggle='collapse' href='#panel' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='panel'>Link One</a>
          <a id='link-two' data-toggle='collapse' href='#panel' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='panel'>Link Two</a>
          <a id='link-three' data-toggle='collapse' href='#panel' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='panel'>Link Three</a>
     </div>
     <div id='panel' class='panel collapse'>
    *dynamic content related to link triggered*
     </div>

</div>
```

I've found these posts about the question :

[Bootstrap How to get element clicked to collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49982315/bootstrap-how-to-get-element-clicked-to-collapse)

[How to get the clicked element in Bootstrap collapse event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596773/how-to-get-the-clicked-element-in-bootstrap-collapse-event)

[Bootstrap modal relatedTarget is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187370/bootstrap-modal-relatedtarget-is-undefined/26187487#26187487)

But unfortunately, none of them works nor gave me an answer.

I tried to find `event.relatedTarget` but there is no such things in the `show.bs.collapse` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that Bootstrap provides the clicked element either, so you can simply track it yourself and use it in the callback.

```js
let currentButtonId;

$('.buttons a').click(e => {
  currentButtonId = e.target.id;
});

$('#panel').on('show.bs.collapse', e => {
  $('#panel').text(currentButtonId + ' was clicked');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='container'>
  <div class='buttons'>
    <a id='link-one' data-toggle='collapse' href='#panel' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='panel'>Link One</a>
    <a id='link-two' data-toggle='collapse' href='#panel' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='panel'>Link Two</a>
    <a id='link-three' data-toggle='collapse' href='#panel' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='panel'>Link Three</a>
  </div>

  <div id='panel' class='panel collapse'>
    *dynamic content related to link triggered*
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```